# Pick an item from the next line base on a condition

Tags: java, spring-boot

[enter image description here][1]Good morning everyone, please I am reading a file that has multiple entries, I am supposed to get an appSessionId from the first entry line then look for the requestMap in the next line that has the same appSessionId.

Here is my code:

```
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
        for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
            if (line.contains("Inside /buyairtime")) {
                String[] item = line.split("\\|");
                String AppSessionId = item[1].trim();
                logger.info("SessionId =" + sessionId + " AppSessionId =" + AppSessionId);

                line = br.readLine(); // Jump to the next line
                if (line.contains(AppSessionId) && line.contains("requestBody")) {

                    String[] request = line.split("\\|");
                    String requestBody = request[2].replace("#", "").trim();
                    String[] requestElement = requestBody.split("=");
                    String requestItem = requestElement[1].trim();
                    logger.info("SessionId =" + sessionId + " requestBody =" + requestItem);

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(requestItem);
                        String transactionId = (String) jsonObject.get("transactionid");
                        logger.info("SessionId =" + sessionId + " transactionId = " + transactionId);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }


                line = br.readLine();  //Jump to the next line
                if (line.contains(AppSessionId) && line.contains("responseMap")) {
                    String[] response = line.split("\\|");
                    String responseMap = response[1].trim();
                    logger.info("SessionId =" + sessionId + " responseMap =" + responseMap);
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

the issue here is my second if statement is not executing, any help will be appreciated, I have attached an image for the log file entry lines.

Example of log file entries

```
2021-09-22 23:55:41.294  INFO 293404 --- [http-nio-8090-exec-62] g.c.vodafone.MCASBroker.model.LdapUtil   : AppSessionId: MB-11FFECB23437494 
| Attribute Value: EVENT=SENDTEXT;ID=;STATUS=PASS;REASON=Success - Adjustment Applied ,New Balance Is 0,New CED Is 20211221; New Balance Is 0

2021-09-22 23:55:41.294  INFO 293404 --- [http-nio-8090-exec-62] g.c.vodafone.MCASBroker.model.LdapUtil   : AppSessionId: MB-11FFECB23437494 
| responseMap:: {"res":"00","rd":"EVENT=SENDTEXT;ID=;STATUS=PASS;REASON=Success - Adjustment Applied ,New Balance Is 0,New CED Is 20211221; New Balance Is 0"}
```

Comment: Hi, can you post some more of your code? is it in a loop? please post some more and don't use image for the log file, you can add it as code also in order members to be able to copy paste it when trying to replicate your issue. thanks

Comment: moreover `AppSessionId` is it a variable or a string `"AppSessionId"`? If it is a variable what's its value? You need to post more of your method or class that does the log file reading/processing.

Comment: Please no screenshots!!!! Edit your question and copy-paste code please!

Comment: See my previous comment, screenshots of code are not useful, edit your question and add the code itself. if you post screenshots your question will be downvoted and/or closed

Comment: I updated my code now

Comment: Thanks. Please do the same with the log file (or a part of it that works reproduces the output of your code)

Comment: I have add it too

Comment: Sorry but the lines you posted are too few, giving this as input it wont get past `if (line.contains("Inside /buyairtime")) {`. Please post a whole piece of the log file that works correctly until the problem you are facing. Read here on Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add this dependency in your pom

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.unix4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>unix4j-command</artifactId>
        <version>0.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

2. This is the code to find the responseMap

```
File file = new File(decompressedFilePath);
List<Line> lines = Unix4j.grep(AppSessionId, file).toLineList();

 String transactionId = null;
 for (Line grepLine : lines) {
      String grepLineStr = grepLine.toString();                                                                                 
      if (grepLineStr.contains("responseMap")) {
          String[] response = grepLineStr.split("\\|");
          String responseMap = response[1].trim();
          String[] responseMap2 = responseMap.split("::");
          String responseMapItem = responseMap2[1].trim();
          logger.info("SessionId =" + sessionId + " responseMap =" + responseMapItem); 
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To get requestMap that is not in the next line I used grep by using Unix4j library to search it through the file and get it.

Comment: Can you include the command or script that you used to achieve that? Without that information, this answer probably won't be very useful for future readers with a similar problem.